# Serving pharo seaside 3.0 with lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, pharo, seaside

I am trying to serve my app with lighttpd. With seaside 2.8 the following worked in my lighttpd.conf:

```
proxy.server = ( "/pharo" => (
    ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8080, "check-local" => "disable"))
)
```

but with seaside 3.0 it rewrites the url to say http://localhost/pharo when accessing it over a network.

Anyone been able to serve pharo and seaside 3 with lighttpd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following did work, I uncommented the following line in this method like so:

```
WARequestHandler>>url
    | url |
    url := self basicUrl.
    self serverPath isNil ifFalse: [ url parsePath: self serverPath ].
    self serverProtocol isNil ifFalse: [ url scheme: self serverProtocol ].
    "self serverHostname isNil ifFalse: [ url host: self serverHostname ]."
    self serverPort isNil ifFalse: [ url port: self serverPort ].

    ^ url
```

In my seaside configuration of my application all the Server settings (Resource Base Url, Server Hostname, Server Path, Server Port, Server Protocol) are unspecified.

It seems like seaside is trying to get the server settings from some applications parent but i can't chase it.

EDIT: Ok, thanks to Lukas (see comment), all I had to do was reset the #serverHostname in my application configuration found at "Dispatcher: /" to nil (unspecified).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had the code of Seaside 2.8 in mind and didn't compare with Seaside 3.0 where URLs are relative by default. Instead of changing the Seaside code I suggest that you reset the `#serverHostname` in your application configuration to `nil`.

Comment: Thank you that worked, now I feel dumb that it was right there and so obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

In the seaside config of your app, put your IP address in the Server Hostname field

Comment: Problem is that my mac's IP is not static, it changes everyday I boot which means I will have to change the server hostname daily

Comment: why don't you just use your computer hostname then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like lighttpd forwards the original hostname different than Apache does. Put a `#halt` in `WAUrl>>#takeServerParametersFromRequest:` and inspect the incoming request `aRequest`. Presumably there is a header field called `X-Forwarded-Host` that contains the original host name, if so change the method as follows:

```
WAUrl>>takeServerParametersFromRequest: aRequest
    "Retrieves scheme, hostname and basepath from the request unless already set."

    scheme isNil
        ifTrue: [ self scheme: aRequest url scheme ].
    host isNil ifTrue: [ 
        aRequest headers at: 'x-forwarded-host' ifPresent: [ :value | self parseAuthority: value  ].
        host isNil 
            ifTrue: [ aRequest headers at: 'host' ifPresent: [ :value | self parseAuthority: value ] ] ].
    path isNil
        ifTrue: [ aRequest headers at: 'base' ifPresent: [ :value | self parsePath: value ] ]
```

If this (or something similar) solves your problem, please [create a ticket](http://code.google.com/p/seaside/issues/list).

Comment: Hi Lukas, I put the halt where you said but it did not halt because the takeServerParametersFromRequest: method does not get called.